# CV-qualified base classes in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

While refactoring some C++11 code, I stumbled upon a strange thing. Namely, it seems to be impossible to define a CV-qualified (`const`, `volatile` or `const volatile`) base class, e.g:

```
struct A { int a = 0; };
struct B: A const {}; // Error here with Clang and GCC!
```

However, the following compiles without errors:

```
struct A { int a = 0; };
using AC = A const;
struct B: AC {};      // NO ERROR HERE!? Qualifiers are ignored.
int main() {
  B b;
  b.a = 42;           // NO ERROR modifying a field of const base.
  return b.a;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What in the C++ standards prohibits defining a CV-qualified base class, if at all?
2. Why does the second example compile?

PS: Since this is a <kbd>language-lawyer</kbd> question, please provide references to the C++ standard.

Comment: You may still use const composition...

Comment: Adding to what jarrod42 said, what does "B is a `const` A" mean? Isn't B `const` then, too?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. The grammar prohibits it. The base classes are specified with the *base-clause* production specified at the start of section 10 of the standard. It eventually resolves to *base-type-specifier*, which is *class-or-decltype*, which is either a `decltype` construct or a *nested-name-specifier[opt] class-name*. Note that this leaves no place for a cv-specifier.
2. The typedef name fits in the grammar. 9.1/5 says "A typedef-name that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also a class-name." The const is simply ignored.
3. The const is simply ignored. Base class subobjects cannot be const on their own. 9.1/5 says "If a typedef-name that names a cv-qualified class type is used where a class-name is required, the cv-qualifiers are ignored."

Comment: It is also relevant to question 1 that 9.1/5 also says that "A *typedef-name* (7.1.3) that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also a *class-name*." The grammar rules in the standard do not explicitly contain *typedef-name* under *class-name*. For some reason this is only given a note in the appendix.

Answer (score 7):

It is actually the full object you create that is const or not const, classes are not cv-qualified.

In `using AC = A const;` the const is simply ignored when used for inheriting.

Comment: Yes, I figured, but why?

Comment: `AC` is really `A const` and not just `A` : [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cf24bd593d2f895).

Comment: @jotik The defining fathers did'nt see any use for a cv-partitioned object, I don't think it is more behind this decision than that